# .net library class not updated in web page

Tags: asp.net, class-library

I just created a new web site in Visual Studio 2012. I also created a new Class Library. I added a class, another class inside that first class and then a method. I compiled the library and added as the reference in the bin folder for the web site. 
In a aspx.cs page I can now see my new method. Great. I go to create a second method in the same location, go back in my aspx.cs page, can't see it. It says there is definition for this method.
I compile the class library just in case. Can't see it. I clean the solution, build the whole solution, still can't see it.
I actually have to remove the reference from the bin folder of the web site and add it back so that now I can see the second method.

I worked on another project where (I believe) things were set up the same way (web site + class library) and by typing the new method in the class and saving the file was enough to reach this method from an aspx page.

What can I change in my solution so that the new method in the class library can be seen directly?

ps: the aspx.cs page has `using myLibrary;` at the top;

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your solution that you are using the References folder.  Right-click it, choose "Add Reference" and then use the Solution tab to reference your class library project.  Taking this approach, every time you update your class library the web project will automatically receive the update.

It sounds like you might be adding the binary to the BIN folder of the website project and then referencing it from there?

Comment: Well done. I was browsing for the dll file directly, not by the project. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if build is going to debug folder or bin folder. If you are referencing project then make sure that build order is correct and dependency set accordingly. Also check for class library or project referred solution is not building on client profile, select targeted framework.

Comment: Thank you Amit, all of this was set up correctly. All I had to do was to refer the project, not the bin file.